# How can I "count characters" in a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not sure if count is the right word to use because it doesn't really matter to me how many there are, but let me explain. My data will be formatted like this: `(hi,(1,2),hey),(yo,(3,(rawr),4),howdy)` and I have no control over how many dimensions there are. And I want to grab the lowest groups 
 `["hi", Array[], "hey"]` and `["yo", Array[], "howdy"]` So if there was a way to "count" I could count the open parenthesis, and then count the closed ones and when it hits 0, that's when the regex ends. For example:

```
(hi,(1,2),hey),(yo,(3,(rawr),4),howdy)
1---2---1----0-1---2--3----2--1------0
```

Now with that being said, *I don't believe counting is possible* but what I want is a subsitute solution. This is what I have so far `/\([^\(]*?\)/` but that only returns the highest level group from each of the low-level groups aka `(1,2)` and `(rawr)`.

Comment: This is very easily achieved without regex; is regex a requirement?

Comment: Not with javascript but easily done with PHP: `$re = '/\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)/';`

Comment: @ridgerunner should mention that JavaScript doesn't provide recursive (the ?R bit) expression matches.

Comment: @cheeken - yes I know it could be done without a regex, but I want to use a regex if I can.

Comment: same comment as @cheeken. Why do you want a regex, is it homework?

Comment: Bracket matching cannot be done with regex, unless it supports recursive regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a stack to track the `(`and`)`.

```
Array.reduce(
    '(hi,(1,2),hey),(yo,(3,(rawr),4),howdy)',
    function(x,y){
        if(y=='(')
            return [x[0]+1, x[1]+(x[0]+1)]
        else if(y==')')
            return [x[0]-1, x[1]+(x[0]-1)]
        else
            return [x[0], x[1]+'-']
    },
    [0,'']
)[1]
```

Try it in `firebug` console.

Comment: I would like to do this using a regex.

Comment: @Aust Javascript's regex doesn't support an sort of expression which could match nested parentheses. Some other languages do, but in Javascript, you have to use a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the original use-case and @Barmar's use-case - and it counts the parenthesis, if you really wanted that...

Also, I added arbitrary spaces all over the data strings - just in case (since you have no control over the incoming data)

```
var results = [];
var dataString = "(hi, (1,2) , hey), ( yo,( 3, ( rawr   ), 4) ,   howdy  )";
//var dataString = "(hi, (1 , 2 ), (3, 4),   hey), (yo ,(3,(rawr ), 4), howdy)";


var dataSplit = dataString.split(",");

var trimRegex = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
var openParensRegex = /\(/;
var closeParensRegex = /\)/;
var parensRegex = /\(|\)/;

var parensCount = 0;

for (var x = 0, lenx = dataSplit.length; x < lenx; x++){
    var cleanString = dataSplit[x].replace(trimRegex, "");

    if (openParensRegex.test(cleanString)){ parensCount++; };

    if (parensCount < 2){
        results.push(cleanString.replace(parensRegex, "").replace(trimRegex, ""));
    };

    if (closeParensRegex.test(cleanString)){ parensCount--; };
};

console.log(results);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This returns all items in one array `["hi", "hey", "yo", "howdy"]` but I want it to return `["hi", Array[], "hey"]` and `["yo", Array[], "howdy"]` sorry if I was unclear on that.

Comment: Ah, yes, I misunderstood your original post. Now I've been trying to build the result set as desired using recursion, but I can't quite get it. Anyway, there's not a single JavaScript RegExp that can do it, if that's what you were hoping for... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The following script might help, it will identify the parenthesis levels:

```
var string="(hi,(1,2),hey),(yo,(3,(rawr),4),howdy)",i=0;
while (string.indexOf("(")>=0) {
    i++;
    string=string.replace(/\(([^()]+)\)/g,"|l"+i+"|$1|l"+i+"|");
}
```

Result:
|l2|hi,|l1|1,2|l1|,hey|l2|,|l3|yo,|l2|3,|l1|rawr|l1|,4|l2|,howdy|l3|

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GfUZh/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the highest levels you can probably do it with regex by finding the intersection points, in this case `),(`.

```
var str = '(hi,(1,2),hey),(yo,(3,(rawr),4),howdy)';
var re = /(\(.+\)),(\(.+\))/;
var results = re.exec(str);
results.shift(); // remove first item which is useless
console.log(results); //=> ["(hi,(1,2),hey)", "(yo,(3,(rawr),4),howdy)"]
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/fFmfE/

Comment: I don't think that will work. What if the input looks like `(hi,(1,2),(3,4),hey),(yo,(3,(rawr),4),howdy)`? You'll match the `),(` between `(1,2)` and `(3,4)`, which are not at the highest level.

Comment: I don't know if that's the case, at least by looking at the example, there are no other places of intersection.

Comment: He said "I have no control over how many dimensions there are", which I interpret to mean that the nested lists can be grouped in arbitrary ways.

Comment: Yes @Barmar is correct. They can be nested in arbitrary ways.